# Having some trouble with deleting records by using php, ajax,mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to network programming area. Currently, I'm trying to establish a website which can make some adjustment on user-list. 
Now, adding and showing are working properly. But have some issue on deleting.I did not using Ajax on on adding and showing. So maybe something wrong with that. I googled this answer for days.
Very appreciate for your help.

This is the ajax Code

```
function member_del(obj,id){
    layer.confirm('Are you sure？',function(index){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'remove.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {IDS:id},
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                $(obj).parents("tr").remove();
                layer.msg('delete!',{icon:1,time:1000});
            },
            error:function(data) {
                console.log(data.msg);
            },
        });
    });
}
```

This this PHP Back-end code

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1:8880";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "fire_alarm";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$code = $_POST["IDS"];
$sql = "DELETE FROM Client WHERE Client_id='$code'";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$conn->close();
?>
```

The Developer tool shows undefined all the time.

here is html code which called ajax function

`echo "<td class=\"td-manage\"><a title=\"edit\" href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"member_edit('edit','member-add.html','4','','510')\" class=\"ml-5\" style=\"text-decoration:none\"><i class=\"Hui-iconfont\">&#xe6df;</i></a> <a title=\"delete\" href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"member_del(this,id)\"id=\"<?php echo $ids; ?>\" class=\"ml-5\" style=\"text-decoration:none\"><i class=\"Hui-iconfont\">&#xe6e2;</i></a></td>";`

Sorry for the bad formatting, this is my first time asking question.

Comment: Put your code in `code block` and not as a link to a picture.

Comment: This is abit hard to fix with only this information? Have you tried looking at the Browser Dev tools  and check the headers of the request? Also what part of the code is the line 127?

Comment: Use OOP or procedural. Don't merge. You are open to SQL injections parameterize. It doesn't make sense to escape the quotes that are used in the SQL to encapsulate the string. If they aren't needed remove them... but **really you should parameterize**.

Comment: Thank you for the information and sorry for the bad formatting. I'm trying to make some change on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upon inspecting your code. 
I may be wrong but it seems you have a typo with your $conn
[image]

Which I suspect the reason you have error at line 127

And there's $query, you should put the $sql in that. That will surely throw an error.

Also a Tip:
Make sure to sanitize your data before inserting it on a query.
Use a parameterize query as much as possible. Because this may lead you to a SQL injection vulnerabilities. You may use the PDO or just sanitize the $_POST['IDs'] first

Comment: I fixed typo still doesn't working and I'm trying to sanitize now.Thank you sir!

Comment: Have you change the $query to $sql ?

Comment: Yes, still nothing.

Comment: You may check the Developer Tools. Go to Network tab and try to request again your request. That's one way to debug this. http://prntscr.com/k5vwni

Comment: I don't have the query para, instead I get a section called from data and shows this  
line:
IDS: <?php echo 405; ?>
I think my query failed.

Comment: That's just an example. There should be a payload that represents the ID in that panel

Comment: wow, it is working now. Thank you very much for the debugging tutorial. I change my html code from id =  <?php echo 405; ?> to id = $ids then mysql deleted the record from database. However, html still shows delete error and shows undefined. That is very weird.

Comment: Now it's working perfectly! Thank you again and wish you have a wonderful day!